# What is this error trying to tell me in NetBeans?

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, compiler-errors

So I've been working on my program, using GUI for the first time in java. I think I have everything how it supposed to be, but is giving me one error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at GUIProgram.<init>(GUIProgram.java:41)
    at Inventory.main(Inventory.java:12)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)
```

I don't know what exactly I have to do, I keep trying to fix it, but I can't.

If you need more information to find out what is wrong, please let me know.

**Edit** (copied from comment)

```
Product[] array = new Product[table.length]; 
float total = 0; float fee = 0; 
for(Product p: array) { 
  total += p.getTotal(); 
  fee += p.getRestockingFee();
}
```

This is the GUIProgram class I am building.

```
    import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GUIProgram extends JFrame
{

     public GUIProgram()
     {
        super("Welcome to the Inventory Program");

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        String[] columnNames = {"Item", "Item No.", "Unit", "Price"};


        Product[] table = new Product[5];

        table[0] = new Product("chocolate", 1023, 124, 1.50f);
        table[1] = new Product("ice cream", 1543, 170, 3.35f);
        table[2] = new Product("milk", 1265, 230, 2.40f);
        table[3] = new Product("orange juice", 1653, 199, 0.60f);
        table[4] = new Product("cereal", 1534, 176, 3.50f);

        for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++)
        {
         JTextField textfield1 = new JTextField(table.length);
         add(textfield1);

           float total = 0;
           float fee = 0;

           for(Product p: table)
           {
                 total += p.getTotal();
                 fee += p.getRestockingFee();

            }

           JTextField textfield2 = new JTextField(table.length);
           textfield2 = new JTextField(String.format("The total value of the Fruits Inventory is: %.2f", total));
           add(textfield2);

           JTextField textfield3 = new JTextField(table.length);
           textfield3 = new JTextField(String.format("The total restocking fee is: %.2f", fee));
           add(textfield3);
         }     
     }  
}
```

I'm just trying to build a GUI for this array.

Comment: There is something maybe declared but you forget to initial it, try to post a brief of both  classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says there is a source file called `GUIProgram.java`, its 41th line has some method call on `null` reference

By

```
Product[] array = new Product[table.length];
```

You declared that you will have an array of Product and you now have space for table.lengh Product references in array

all those references are still `null` , You need to initialize each product

and to do so

```
for(Product p: array) { 
  // initialization
  p = new Product();
  total += p.getTotal(); 
  fee += p.getRestockingFee();
}
```

Comment: Okay this is what I have on those lines:

"    Product[] array = new Product[table.length];
  
           float total = 0;
           float fee = 0;
        
           for(Product p: array)
           {
            total += p.getTotal();
            fee += p.getRestockingFee();
           }    "

I thought this was fine. I'm retaining the information from a third class call Product. The code is not even alerting me of any problem.

Comment: Ugh... I don't know how to display part of the code in the comment window.

Comment: I deleted the for(Product p: array), because I already had the array declared. It worked, but now is display the total of each array, and there are five arrays declared like this:

` table[0] = new Product("Milk", 1234, 224, 2.10) `

I have four more, but they are not even displayed on my Panel.

Comment: More specific question would help me to answer you

Comment: I'm sorry I'm such a newbie at this. I've been learning almost on my own. I don't ask questions, but I'm trying to, because programming is getting very difficult, and I'm barely starting to learn.

Comment: ok no problem hope you have read stackoverflow rules while registering, and what is your specific question now

Comment: I'm trying to make the arrays appear on the window I built, but I could only see the total value of each array, and the total value of the restocking fee, and they are editable. I need to make them appear only once, at the bottom of the panel, and the arrays on top. I'm still gonna try, I actually like trying to figure this out.

Comment: ok so this question has been answered and can be marked as answered, another question if you have could be posted separately

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using a variable inside your constructor before you have initialized it.

Random example:

```
Button runButton; //declared, but not initialized
button.SetColor(0, 0, 0); //calling the SetColor method on the uninitialized variable will cause it to go bang and give you a NullPointerException
```